# How to display 'last modified' date on publishing page using content editor web part?

Tags: 2010, javascript, html, content-editor-web-part, cewp

For a number of pages within my site, I need to display the date that the page was last modified. I know this is possible using a custom view for the page library, but for my purposes, that is not an acceptable solution.

Using information I found online ( I can't seem to find the source right now), I created a .htm file and linked it to a Content editor web part.

The code within the .htm file is as follows

```
<HTML xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Time Stamper</TITLE>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:Associated_x0020_with msdt:dt="string"></mso:Associated_x0020_with>
<mso:TemplateUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:TemplateUrl>
<mso:xd_ProgID msdt:dt="string"></mso:xd_ProgID>
<mso:_CopySource msdt:dt="string">http://theurl/to/the/code/Document/show last mod.htm</mso:_CopySource>
<mso:Order msdt:dt="string">500.000000000000</mso:Order>
<mso:_SourceUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:_SourceUrl>
<mso:_SharedFileIndex msdt:dt="string"></mso:_SharedFileIndex>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
update = new Date(document.lastModified)
theMonth = update.getMonth() + 1
theDate = update.getDate()
theYear = update.getFullYear()
document.writeln("<I>Last updated:" + theMonth + "/" + theDate + "/" + theYear + "</I>")
</SCRIPT>
<HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This code almost works, but it displays the date the page was last visited, not modified.

Comment: on your rest query call you want to change the field "timelastmodified" for "Modified" that's the system name for the last time the item or document was modified

Comment: @mike thanks for the tip. I goofed in the original post and pasted the wrong code. now i've put in the correct code that shows the date the page was last visited. I tried replacing 'last modified' in the "Update = " line with 'Modified' but that returned an error.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem here when migrating from 2007. For some reason, it is not included in the new page layouts, so we wrote a script. Hopefully you can get something from this that will help you:

```
// Fix wiki pages by adding last modified info to the bottom for migrated wikis
function FixMigratedWikiPages() {
    var sItemId = typeof(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId) == "undefined" ? 0 : _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId;
    var  sListTemplate = typeof(_spPageContextInfo.listBaseTemplate) == "undefined" ? 0 : _spPageContextInfo.listBaseTemplate;

    if (sItemId != 0 && sListTemplate == 119) 
    {
        // Get GUID of the document library where the page is stored
        var spageListId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
        sPageListId = spageListId.replace("{", "'").replace("}", "'");
        // Form the REST URL to get the Last Modified and Last Modified By Information
        var sRestApiRequestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid" + sPageListId + ")/items(" + sItemId + ")?$select=Modified,ID,Editor/Title,Editor/EMail,*&$expand=Editor";

        getWikiData(sRestApiRequestUrl ).then(function (spData) {
            addDateToWikiFooter(spData);
        }); 
    }
}


function addDateToWikiFooter(spData) {
    var strDate = spData.d.Modified;
    var date = new Date(strDate);
    date = formatDate(date);

    var modifiedBy = spData.d.Editor.Title;

    $('*[id*=WikiField]:visible').each(function() {
        var count = $('*[id=wikiModified]:visible').length;
        if(count == 0) {
            $(this).append('<br/><div id="wikiModified" class="ms-descriptiontext">Last modified at ' + date + ' by ' + modifiedBy + '</div>');
            return false;
        }
    }); 
}

function formatDate(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + "  " + strTime;
}

function getWikiData(query) {

    var relativePageURL = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath;
    var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;         

    //var query = siteURL + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/"+ relativePageURL +"')?$select=TimeLastModified,ModifiedBy/Title,ModifiedBy/LoginName&$expand=ModifiedBy";

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);

        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

$(function() {
    FixMigratedWikiPages();
});
```